# jquery ajax response from php undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Having a problem getting a form with ajax to get a php response.  The javascript seems right because it works if I erase everything on login_ajax.php and only use the following

```
echo 'CORRECT' 
//or 
echo 'INCORRECT'
```

Once I use the real php code, the ajax doesn't get any response from the PHP.
Even more weird if I remove the

```
return false
```

from  the javascript and then submit the form, I do see CORRECT or INCORRECT being displayed on the login_ajax.php in the browser.

HTML:

```
<form id="login" action='login_ajax.php' method="get">

    <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="nano@nano.com"></label>
    <label>Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="x"></label>

    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <div id="straight_response">php response here</div>
    <div id="message">status</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['password'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $stored_pass = "123";

    if ($password == $stored_pass) {
        echo "CORRECT";
    } else {
        echo "INCORRECT";
    }
}
//Javascript works when using one of the two lines below instead of the code above
//echo 'INCORRECT';
//echo 'CORRECT'
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#login').submit(function(){


var email;
    var password;

    email       = $('#email').val();
    password    = $('#password').val();

    var data = {};
    data.email  = email;
    data.password   = password;

    var options = {};
    options.dataType = 'text';
    options.type = 'get';
    options.url= 'login_ajax.php';
    options.success = function (response) {
    //  jQuery.trim(response);
        console.log(response.results);
        console.log(response.query);
        $('#always').text(response);

        if (response === 'CORRECT') {
            $('#message').text('you got it right');
            console.log("good combination");
        }
        else if (response === 'INCORRECT') {
            $('#message').text('sorry, try again');
            console.log("bad combination");
        }
    };

    $.ajax(options);
    return false;
});//#login function
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be beneficial to see your PHP code as well.

Comment: Where in your javascript code are you submitting the login form data to login_ajax.php?

Comment: first thing to do is to dump out what's in your $_GET array. (You might want to use post, anyway, to reduce problems with browser caching.) See if it matches what you expect.

Comment: Also using post won't advertise people's passwords quite as flagrantly. Although they still won't be safe.

Comment: @JerrySeeger I would like if you could elaborate on the *password advertising*. We often overlook AJAX's security issues, it would be great to know a bit more of why it would make the difference.

Comment: I'll try to find a good link, but using GET will put the password into the URL passed back to the server for all to see.

Comment: Thank you @JerrySeeger I'm well aware of GET displaying everything in the URL. It was a mistake on my part to use a login as an example. I should have used something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh god I actually spent 40 minutes trying to understand your problem inside out, and turns out that the fact is that **you don't pass the `data` you collect from the form** to the PHP through AJAX.

Easy fix, add this line before you make your call:

```
options.data = data;
```

Though, as [the documentation states](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> It is often unnecessary to directly call this function, as several higher-level alternatives like `$.get()` and `.load()` are available and are easier to use.

In your case I think `$.get()` works just as fine. **Although** you might want to take a look of what JerrySeeger said in the comments, looks like using `GET` for password might represent a huge security hole, also you should perhaps be using SSL.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just looking at your response I knew that would definitely be it. I knew about the data too but I just couldn't see it. Thank you again.

Comment: and no worries about the security I'm just using a login form as an example. The real thing is not a login form but an image upload and process script.